# Clickable Image - Avoid touching another area

Tags: android, image, click

I am trying to make a `clickable` imageView. For the that I am using invisible buttons on it. But my question is when I click , I want to avoid touching on an empty area or other `clickable` part since the shape is not linear. How can I do that?

Comment: You are using  click able image than why you are using invisible buttons on it??

Comment: Your Question is not understandable.

Comment: i want to create a clickable image of continents there is just one image. For clicked each continent I want to keep its info. @Subhalaxmi Nayak

Comment: i want to create a clicable image of continents there is just one image. For clicked each continent I want to keep its info.@shweta_jain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use an invisible button to do that, you are just drawing several times the same pixels for nothing, and this will lead to poor performance.

What you can do is make your `ImageView` clickable (as @shkschneider told you) and use the `ImageView`'s onClickListener methods to handle the onClick behaviour (the same way you would do with a button).

**EDIT :**

If I understood well, you're looking for a way to set several clickable areas among one `ImageView`. In that case, [here](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/images-with-clickable-areas/) is a good tutorial about it.

Comment: i want to create a clickable image of continents there is just one image. For clicked each continent I want to keep its info.@VieuMa @shkschneider

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a Button, use an ImageView made clickable.

```
<ImageView android:clickable="true"
```